# How to count the total number of chars words and lines in two files and add them up to come up with the total?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

So here I got the code that counts the number of lines chars and words in a file.Now I need to implement the same thing for multiple files. Basically my code should read the number of chars words and lines in each file and should produce a total of chars words and lines (adding up the count of chars words and lines from each file.I also need help executing the code for poorly formed arguments,file not found,and unrecognized arguments. Here is my code, I tried to compile it but it is only able to read the number of chars words and characters in each file and not add up the total.Thank you guys.Any help would be greatly appreciated or suggestions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>




using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{

if (argc<2){
    cout<<"You did not enter enough arguments, Please try again, close this cd window and enter the correct filename"<<endl;
}
else{
    string filename;
    ifstream thefile;
    int i;
    for(i=1,i<=argc;(i++);){
    filename=argv[i];
    int charactercounter=0, linecounter=1, wordcounter=1, totalLines, totalWords,totalCharacters;
    thefile.open(filename);
        if(!thefile.is_open()){
            cout<<"file does not exist"<<endl;
        }
        else if(thefile.fail()){
            cout<<"arguments can't be recognized"<<endl;
        }

    if(thefile.is_open() && thefile.good()){
    while(!thefile.eof()){
         char ch;
         while(ch!=EOF){
            charactercounter++;
             totalCharacters=totalCharacters+charactercounter;
            if (ch=='\n')
                linecounter++;
                totalLines=totalLines+linecounter;
                if (ch==' ')
                wordcounter++;
                totalWords=totalWords+wordcounter;
            ch=thefile.get();

        }
        }




        cout<<setw(12)<<"Lines"<<' '<< linecounter;
        cout<<' ';
        cout<<setw(12)<<"words"<<' '<< wordcounter;
        cout<<' ';
        cout<<setw(12)<<"characters"<<' '<< charactercounter;
        cout<<' ';
        cout<<setw(12)<<"filename"<<' '<<argv[i];
        cout<<' ';
        cout<<setw(12)<<"totallines"<<' '<<totalLines;
        cout<<' ';
        cout<<setw(12)<<"totalwords"<<' '<<totalWords;
        cout<<' ';
        cout<<setw(12)<<"totalchars"<<' '<<totalCharacters;
        cout<<' ';


        thefile.close();
    }

    }
    }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: This code is not easy for human to read and that makes looking for bugs more difficult. Should use function/class for different parts of the program. That way you can write unit tests to check which function/class does not behave as expected, instead of searching the whole program for many times to look for each bug. Designing a good software architecture before writing the program and writing unit tests might help.

Answer (score 0):

Added some comments, functions, and classes to make the code easier to read.

I also try to preserve the bugs in the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool argc_checker(const int argc, const char* const argv[]) {
    // Check commandline arguments
    // If no problem, return true. Otherwise, return false.
    if (argc < 2) {
        cout << "You did not enter enough arguments, Please try again, "
                "close this cd window and enter the correct filename" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool check_file(const ifstream& thefile) {
    // Return true if the file is ok. Otherwise, return false
    if (!thefile.is_open()) {
        cout << "file does not exist" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    if (thefile.fail()) {
        cout << "arguments can't be recognized" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    if (thefile.is_open() && thefile.good()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Word_counter {
    // Count the number of character, words, and lines by taking characters
    // one by one.
public:
    Word_counter() { reset(); }
    void take(const char ch) {
        ++_n_chars;
        if (ch == ' ') ++_n_words;
        if (ch == '\n') ++_n_lines;
    }
    void reset() {
        // Reset the word counter.
        _n_chars = 0;
        _n_words = 1;
        _n_lines = 1;
    }
    const int n_chars() const { return _n_chars; }
    const int n_words() const { return _n_words; }
    const int n_lines() const { return _n_lines; }
private:
    int _n_chars;
    int _n_words;
    int _n_lines;
};
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Total_word_counter {
    // Take a word counter and add its count to total counts.
public:
    Total_word_counter() { reset(); }
    void take(const Word_counter& wc) {
        _n_total_chars += wc.n_chars();
        _n_total_lines += wc.n_lines();
        _n_total_words += wc.n_words();
    }
    void reset() {
        // Reset the total word counter
        _n_total_chars;
        _n_total_lines;
        _n_total_words;
    }
    const int n_total_chars() const { return _n_total_chars; }
    const int n_total_words() const { return _n_total_words; }
    const int n_total_lines() const { return _n_total_lines; }
private:
    int _n_total_chars;
    int _n_total_words;
    int _n_total_lines;
};
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
void simple_print_table(const std::string& name, const T& thing) {
    cout << setw(12) << name << ' ' << thing << ' ';
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // check if arguments are ok. if not, exit the program.
    if (!argc_checker(argc, argv)) exit(1);

    // Create word counters
    Word_counter wc;
    Total_word_counter total_wc;

    // loop over each commandline argument
    for (int i = 1, i <= argc; (i++); ) {
        string filename(argv[i]);
        ifstream the_file(filename);

        // check if file is ok. if not skip to next cycle of the for loop.
        if (!check_file(the_file)) {
            the_file.close();
            continue;
        }
        // loop over each character of the_file.
        char ch;
        while (!the_file.eof() && (ch != EOF)) {
            wc.take(ch);
            ch = the_file.get(); // pass each char to the word counter
        }
        total_wc.take(wc); // add result of word counter to total_wc
        // Print result of counting
        simple_print_table("Lines", wc.n_lines());
        simple_print_table("words", wc.n_words());
        simple_print_table("characters", wc.n_chars());
        simple_print_table("totallines", total_wc.n_total_lines());
        simple_print_table("totalwords", total_wc.n_total_words());
        simple_print_table("totalchars", total_wc.n_total_chars());
        // Rest word counter
        wc.reset(); // reset the wc so it is ready to count next file
        // Close the file
        the_file.close();
    }
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your code has too many nested levels of brackets `{}`. It makes the code very difficult to read.

Comment: Oh damn thanks for that ill try to take out the brackets and do this thank you soo much!! Your the best.